# google AI platform read history on local

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pickle, bucket, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

After training model i would like to save history in mine bucket or any location which i can access later on local

when i run code below on google colab all work fine

```
history = model.fit(training_dataset, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=EPOCHS,
                validation_data=validation_dataset, validation_steps=validation_steps)
#model.summary()
model.save(BUCKET)
#save as pickle
with open('/trainHistoryDict', 'wb') as file_pi:
      pickle.dump(history.history, file_pi)
```

I can read later using

```
history = pickle.load(open('/trainHistoryDict', "rb"))
```

however when run code as a job on  google cloud AI-Platform ( using %%wrotefile) I cannot retrieve history on google colab using pickle load   - im getting 'no such directory'
So how i can run training on AI platform on google cloud and then access history on google colab?
Can i save history.history in bucket ? i tried to use PACKAGE_STAGING_PATH but it didnt worked

Answer (score 1):

found solution

```
subprocess.Popen('gsutil cp history gs://bigdatapart2-storage/history1', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```